# split string wit several delimiters only once

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to split a string with different delimiters. And also just one time... It seems I don't get it :-(. 
for example:

```
test/date-2020-02-10Xinfo
```

what I want is an Array like:

```
[test,Date,2020-02-10,info]
```

I tryed several things, for example:

```
this.informations = this.info.map(i => i.split(/(?:\/|-|X)+/));
```

What I get is
[test,Date,2020,02,10,info]

Comment: Try `i.split(/[\/X]/)`

Comment: And a solution when you first replace `/` or others with `,` and after that a simple `split` ?

Comment: Try `this.info.map(i => i.match(/^([^\/]+)\/([^-]+)-(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})X(.*)/).slice(1));`

Comment: the one @Wiktor Stribiżew wrote was really good. But there is an empty entry in the array array[0]

Comment: Does not `.slice(1)` solve that first item presence issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use declare a regex like

```
/^([^\/]+)\/([^-]+)-(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})X(.*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ho1U3G/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([^-]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `-`
- `-` - a `-` char
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Group 3: four digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits
- `X` - `X` char
- `(.*)` - Group 4: the rest of the string.

Use it like

```
this.info.map(i => i.match(regex).slice(1));
```

The `.slice(1)` will remove the first item from the result array `String#match(RegExp)` returns, i.e. the whole match value (since you only need the captured substrings).